# How can I (or should I) pin a byte array in VB.net, such that the GC does not make copies?

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection

Consider the following, which takes an encrypted password, decrypts it using a certificate from the local computer, and returns it in a SecureString:

```
Public Function Decrypt(EncryptedPasswordBytes as byte()) as SecureString

    Dim Store As New X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher,StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
    Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)

    Dim Cert = Store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                  "0ed0cfd7ffbeb3794013d03c8022f5ed7b45678", False)(0)
    Dim PrivateKey = Cert.GetRSAPrivateKey

    Dim DecryptedPasswordBytes = PrivateKey.Decrypt(EncryptedPasswordBytes,
                                   Security.Cryptography.RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256)

    Dim DecryptedPasswordChars = Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(DecryptedPasswordBytes)

    Array.Clear(DecryptedPasswordBytes, 0, DecryptedPasswordBytes.Length)


    Dim SString As New SecureString

    For Each C In DecryptedPasswordChars
           SString.AppendChar(C)
    Next

    Array.Clear(DecryptedPasswordChars, 0, DecryptedPasswordChars.Length)

    SString.MakeReadOnly()

    Return SString

End Function
```

Array.Clear is called twice to minimize the amount of time the decrypted password is in memory.

However, I'm under the impression that the GC could make copies of these arrays before they are cleared.  Is this something I should worry about, and if so, what is the proper way to pin these arrays such that the GC can not copy them?

Comment: I think it's problematic that you are able to decrypt the password in the first place.  Instead you should be using some sort of salted hash of the password.  This is something you should not try to do yourself.  There are algorithms available with tested solutions, such as PBKDF2.  See [this link](https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing) for an example.

Comment: I know this is late, but I should have mentioned that I'm not trying to validate credentials, I'm trying to store them.  In this case I have an SQL server user password that needs to be stored in a desktop application.  It's ugly no matter how you look at it, but I'm trying to do my best to secure it.